# Can't SSH into Raspberry Pi after changing permissions

Tags: debian, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

`sudo chmod -R 777 /` was entered in an attempt to regain access to directories that were previously accessible, but this caused the SSH connection to be closed and now can no longer be reconnected.  A "Login failed." error is displayed.  The Pi can still be accessed directly.

Any use of `sudo` returns `sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

How can this be reversed?  What did the permission changes do to cause this?

Comment: In practical terms you restore from your backup or reinstall from scratch. You have hosed your system. There are some answers here (I'll see if I can find a duplicate for you) that explain how you might be able to repair your Pi but basically you've broken it.

Comment: Sounds broken, haha.  Reinstall looks like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this by removing the SD card and mounting it in another device under /mnt and chmodding the files under /mnt.

Another option is if you can get it to boot by mounting a rescue image you can run `aptitude reinstall "~i"` which should fix file permissions.

That said unless there is data you can't lose you should reinstall.

Comment: A chroot into the system as root and the `aptitude reinstall` is probably the closest to a decent option.... (For a Pi, it would need to be another ARM-based system, since you use the binaries inside the chroot...)